# Bug with chrome.tabs.create in a loop

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, loops, google-chrome-extension, tabs

On my Chrome extension [Copy All Urls](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-all-urls/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk), I've developed a "paste" feature to open all URL found in the clipboard, with one tab per url.

But this feature doesn't works properly, sometime it works fine, sometimes it opens only a few subset of all URL that it should open.

I suspect Chrome API, and more specifically `chrome.tabs.create` to be responsible for this mistake, so I wrote a little piece of code to test it :

**popup.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-1.7.2_min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="actionTest">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js :**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#actionTest').click(function(e){
        var urlList = ["http://stackoverflow.com/","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page","http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/","http://nodejs.org/","https://github.com/","http://wallbase.cc/","http://www.chromium.org/Home","http://www.photoshoptuto.com/?s=test+chrome+tabs","http://www.youtube.com/","https://www.tumblr.com/","http://www.imdb.com/","http://www.flickr.com/","http://kickass.to/","https://www.dropbox.com/","http://fr.slideshare.net/","http://www.deviantart.com/","http://www.livejournal.com/","http://ohnotheydidnt.livejournal.com/82624099.html","http://www.etsy.com/","http://www.mediafire.com/","http://www.foxnews.com/","http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2013/10/21/obama-addresses-problems-with-health-care-website/"];
        $.each(urlList, function(key, val){
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: val}, function(tab){
                // console.log('openned: '+tab.url);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, urlList contains 22 URL, but when I press the test button I not always have 22 new tabs openned.

What's wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Please, also, post the conteht of your manifest. Do you get any errors on the console (either on your background-oage or popup) ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that the source code is available on github : https://github.com/finalclap/CopyAllUrl_Chrome. Here is the manifest.json : https://github.com/finalclap/CopyAllUrl_Chrome/blob/master/manifest.json

Comment: OK, I'll take a look and come back :) In the meantime, I suggest you consider converting your background-page to an event-page (more info **[here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it myself (due to lack of time), but I believe that the problem is this:

**The problem**
You are creating the tabs from `popup.js`. As soon as a new tab receives focus, the popup (`popup.html`) is closed/hidden and any JavaScript execution stops. This means that there will be so many tabs opened as many `popup.js` managed to create **before** the first tab received focus. So, sometimes it will be all, sometimes some etc.

**The solution**
The solution is to mive the "tab-creating" code in the background page (or better yet event page). E.g.:

```
// ...in popup.js
...
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
        bgPage.openAllURLsInTabs();
    });
...
```

(Of course, there are many approaches possible, e.g. message-passing etc.)

**The demo**
For demonstration purposes, I have put together a tiny extension that opens your 22 URLs is new tabs. For simplicity, it does not feature a popup, just a browser-action.
The file structure is like this:

```
TestCX
     |__background.js
     |__jquery-1.7.2_min.js
     |__manifest.json
```

***background.js:***

```
var urlList = [
    "http://stackoverflow.com/",
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page",
    "http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/",
    "http://nodejs.org/",
    "https://github.com/",
    "http://wallbase.cc/",
    "http://www.chromium.org/Home",
    "http://www.photoshoptuto.com/?s=test+chrome+tabs",
    "http://www.youtube.com/",
    "https://www.tumblr.com/",
    "http://www.imdb.com/",
    "http://www.flickr.com/",
    "http://kickass.to/",
    "https://www.dropbox.com/",
    "http://fr.slideshare.net/",
    "http://www.deviantart.com/",
    "http://www.livejournal.com/",
    "http://ohnotheydidnt.livejournal.com/82624099.html",
    "http://www.etsy.com/",
    "http://www.mediafire.com/",
    "http://www.foxnews.com/",
    "http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2013/10/21/obama-addresses-problems-with-health-care-website/"
];
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    $.each(urlList, function(key, val) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: val }, function(tab) {
            console.log("Opened: " + tab.url);
        });
    });
});
```

***manifest.json:***

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Paste All URLs",
    "version": "2.5",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Paste many URLs"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "jquery-1.7.2_min.js",
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

---

I hope this helps you solve your problem. If not come back for more :)

Comment: I have struggled with a similar issue myself for quite some time, so I should know :) (Although, as noted in my answer, I have not tested OP's code myself, thus I am kind of taking an "educated guess" on the cause of the problem.)

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be a relevant explanation, I will try it after work.

Comment: Ok, it works fine, I moved all the code from popup.js to background.js and used the messaging API to display some message in the popup.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Don't forget my initial comment about turning background-pages to event-pages. They are so much more resource-friendly and responsive :)

Comment: Yes I will do it for a next release.